# How to open port 1645 in OpenShift PHP Cartridges?

Tags: php, port, openshift, freeradius

It's to possible to open port 1645 in Cartridges PHP 5.4, Scales 1 - 3, Web Load Balancer?

How can i do that? I'm trying to install freeradius for my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

The only ports that are externally accessible on OpenShift Online are 80/443/8000/8443.  No other ports can be opened for public access.
You can refer to this page https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html of the Developer Portal for more information on port binding and routing.